Stretch Kafka across security zones inside 1 data center
I have 2 security zones inside a data center. And I want to deploy kafka such that if there is a topic published by Broker-1 in Security zone-1, then this topic is also accessible in Security zone-2 also.
Is stretch cluster the only option for this?
I am doing R&D on the stretch cluster with common zookeeper ensemble as an option while the other option is to have 2 separate clusters deployed across both security zones with dedicated zookeeper ensembles.
Architecture Diagram

This question would fit better in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Kakfa no longer needs Zookeeper and there is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". They repackage Apache Kafka in Confluent Platform.


Is stretch cluster the only option for this?

From the minimal description, no. You can mirror one cluster to another .

such that if there is a topic published by Broker-1 in Security zone-1, then this topic is also accessible in Security zone-2

This is entirely controlled by

advertised.listeners if clients can resolve leader brokers in both zones.
Partition Count on that topic, and if any two partitions live in both zones. This means your brokers need to forward requests across the zone, on their own (so, yes, streched)
replication.factor (same as 2)


R&D on the stretch cluster with common zookeeper ensemble

Please use KRaft. Zookeeper mode is deprecated.

Thank you so much for your detailed response. I am actually a little new to this stuff and struggling to do it correctly. I have added an architecture diagram to my question, can you please review this and let me know if this is a valid depiction of a stretch cluster spread across two security zones in a single data center?


There shouldn't really be an active firewall between two zones where Kafka is deployed. But if so, ensure iptables is allowing bidirectional traffic. 2) The brokers would be numbered 1-6, not two sets of 1-3 (you would have one cluster that is stretched , not two). 3) Schema Registry + Connect should also be a clusters for high availability and scalability. 4) Optional - Look at using WarpStream rather than MinIO for storage options. 5) Just use a cloud hosted Kafka or deploy Strimzi in K8s to make your deployment problems simpler

